# Assembly 64 into a 32bit machine

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit

that's my first question in this large community.

I'm studying at University the correspondace between C++ and Assembly 64 (how compiler translate C++ into assembly) and I'm used to have practice on my 32bit laptop. Now, as long as my laptop is 32bit i can only run a 32 bit ubuntu virtual machine and i can't compile&execute 64bit programs (can't use for example %RAX register because in 32bit i can use just %EAX). Is there a software that make me able to run this programs eventhough i have a 32bit laptop? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can use a virtual machine or an emulator like `qemu`. It won't be fast though.

Comment: Thanks, i'm absolutely not interested into speed. How can i use a 64bit ubuntu virtual machine in my 32bit windows 8 laptop? I've tried but install was not succesfully. Yes, we use qemu to simulate a completely empty of any program machine to test pc feature like virtual memory, cache memory, video memory, keyboard input codes. Anyway i need an environment where i can write my code, compile my code and finally run my program

Comment: You can install 64 bit Ubuntu install a qemu VM. However, I recommend you to use a pre-installed image instead as then you don't have to manually install it.

Comment: Also consider getting a new computer or working remotely on your university's server.

Comment: You *can* compile 64b code on 32b machine. You can't run it. Also most of the virtual x86 machine SW is using native CPU to execute the virtual code, so there's no possibility to virtualize 64b code on 32b CPU by this trick, you need then full emulator running the virtual 64b CPU by emulating it fully (the speed will be horrible). Probably look how to "inject" compiled 64b binaries into qemu (shared file system?), so you can write/compile fast in native OS, and use the slow emulated 64b only for executing+debugging.